# Why doesn't the navigation title show up using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am learning `SwiftUI` using Apple's official tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Everything works perfectly until I try to show a navigation title on a `NavigationView` by calling `.navigationBarTitle`.

I have tried to refresh the live view, restart Xcode, but it still doesn't show up.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Done"))
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct LandmarkList_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkList()
    }
}
#endif
```

Xcode looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

According to the tutorial, it should show the navigation title but it doesn't in my case.

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot link was not working

Comment: @Nizzam I think it works now, plz try again.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

`.navigationBarTitle()` and `.navigationBarItem()` are modifiers on the `View` inside of the `NavigationView`, not on the `NavigationView` itself:

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
            }
            .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Done"))
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

and if you think about it, this makes sense.  As the `View` within the `NavigationView` changes, the new `View` dictates what the title and contents of the navigation bar should be.

Comment: At first I was arguing with my screen, until I re-thought about what you said "the new View dictates what the title and contents of the navigation bar should be" ... and bingo!

Comment: Thought there was something wrong with xcode or swift, until I moved the code inside the NavigationView and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 21):

## Description:

`NavigationView` is just a container around some content. Contents are changing when you navigating from page to page, but the `NavigationView` persists.

The point is that `NavigationView` shows each `view`'s content when it shows it. So it will encapsulate with the destination.

Finally, you should add all navigation modifiers **inside the navigation** (on the content)

> ⚠️ From iOS 14+ you should use `ToolbarItem` instead of `navigationBarItem` like below

---

## Example:

```
struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some. content")

            // iOS 14+
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { Text("Done") }
            }

            // iOS 13-16.4(deprecated) - You can use toolbar now
            // .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Done"))

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
    }
}
```

```
struct Parent: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Content() // This contains navigation modifiers inside the view itself
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The popular answer "says" the same thing, but this answer "shows" it.  Now it is clear to me.

Comment: Value of type 'Text' has no member 'navigationBarItem'

Comment: @RajaSaad updated for current iOS

Answer (score 3):

If someone is looking for **navigation title** with **tab button**, this code may be helpful -

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("SwiftUI")
                .navigationTitle("Screen Title")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Right") {
                        print("Right button tapped!")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are arriving here and using `NavigationStack` (in fact NavigationView has a warning for future deprecation since iOS 16), just put the  `.navigationTitle("My title")` modifier on the content of the `NavigationStack`, not on the `NavigationStack` itself.

e.g.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        List {
            [...]
        }
        .navigationTitle("My title")  //    <<-- !! Modifier goes here !!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.modifier(NavigationView()) had to be added AFTER .navigationBar* modifiers, not before